# SQL Server : get column data from string header

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to retract a column from a table by knowing the header name of the column that I want to retrieve.

```
select @sName
from VPDW.dbo.Fact_Email_MW100
where VesselID = 3763 
  and (cast(UTClogTime as date) >= cast(DateAdd(day, -1, GETUTCDATE()) as date))
```

where

```
Declare @sName nvarchar(max);
```

holds the string name of the column that I want to extract from my table.

Comment: You need to use dynamic SQL for this.

Comment: Could you provide an easy example of this? Not too familiar with SQL yet.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, with XML's abilities to resolve generically defined queries this does not demand for dyanmic SQL and can be solved fully inline. I placed an answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole query needs to be dynamic in order to achieve what you're trying to do. That is, you have to build the SQL and then execute it. Consider something like the following (not tested):

```
declare @sName nvarchar(max)
declare @sql nvarchar(max)

set @sName = 'some_column'

set @sql = 'select ' + @sName + ' from VPDW.dbo.Fact_Email_MW100 where VesselID = 3763 and (cast(UTClogTime as date) >= cast(DateAdd(day,-1,GETUTCDATE()) as date))'
print @sql

exec sp_sqlexec  @sql
```

Comment: Worked flawlessly. Thanks!

Comment: If you don't want to meet [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) then the column name should be validated against the [`sys.columns`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-columns-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) view for the target table. The best practice when assembling object names into dynamic SQL statements is to use [`QuoteName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) to avoid problems with odd names, e.g. `New Table` with a space  or reserved words like `From`.

Comment: @HABO correct and important to mention! Or you can use XML's generic queries.

Comment: William, *The whole query needs to be dynamic*... There is a non-dynamic approach using XML (see my answer).

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes one cannot use dynamic SQL (in VIEWs, iTVFs). In such cases you can uses XML's abilities to deal with generic queries:

```
DECLARE @ColName VARCHAR(100)='name';

SELECT
(
    SELECT TOP 1 * 
    FROM sys.objects
    FOR XML PATH('row'),TYPE
).value('(/row/*[local-name()=sql:variable("@ColName")]/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS ValueAtColumnName;
```

This will get one row of `sys.objects` and return the value for the column `name`.

For your query this would look like

```
Declare @sName nvarchar(max);
SELECT
(
    select *
    from VPDW.dbo.Fact_Email_MW100
    where VesselID = 3763 
      and (cast(UTClogTime as date) >= cast(DateAdd(day, -1, GETUTCDATE()) as date))

).value('(/row/*[local-name()=sql:variable("@sName")]/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS ValueAtColumnName;
```